# Trying to use Local Storage for Reg/Login

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to use local storage to make a basic registration and login screen.
I have managed to get all the basics running but I can't get the fields to save to the local storage to them pull for the login process. I do not believe the HTML is wrong but the Javascript.

Here is the JS:

```
function save() {
   var inputUserName = document.getElementById('regusername');
   var inputPassWord = document.getElementById('regpassword');
   var inputEmail = document.getElementById('regemail');
   localStorage.setItem('username', inputUserName.value);
   localStorage.setItem('email', inputEmail.value);
   localStorage.setItem('password', inputPassWord.value);
}

function check() {

   // Getting data from the register-form
   var inputUserName = localStorage.getItem('username');
   var inputPassWord = localStorage.getItem('password');

   var username = document.getElementById('username');
   var password  = document.getElementById('password');

   if (username.value == inputUserName && password.value == inputPassWord) {
       alert('You have successfully logged in' + inputUserName);
   } else {
       alert('ERROR')
       for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
       alert(localStorage.key(i));
       }
  }

}
```

Comment: FTR : you won't be able to do a serious registration / login screen with localStorage. I guess this question is only for learning purpose?

Comment: By the way, can you post the relevant HTML or a live demo?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I wasn't getting an error, it was just outputting Name, Email and Password but I fixed it. In the HTML the name="" was causing it to not work. I don't understand why honestly if someone could explain that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was my HTML I had a `name="Name"` and it seemed to collide with the input that the user had changing to whatever was in the `name=""` in this case being Name, Email and Password.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the input of the user in a specific field, you need to use something like:

`document.getElementById('username').value;`

You forgot to add the `.value` at the end.

Comment: Oh i'll try this as well!